# Dynamic memory usage, lists in C

Tags: c, list, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

The problem is that I do not print the total of "F", which is in the list, if not send me the following message:

```
Segment violation (`core 'generated)
```

I think the problem lies in the way I move within the cycle for

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define T 5

int menu();
struct nodo{ 
/*Declaración de los campos*/ 
char sexo; 
struct nodo *sig; //Uso de sig como apuntador dentro de la lista al siguiente nodo
};
int tam= sizeof(struct nodo); //Se calcula el tamaño de bytes 

int main(){ 

int i, totalf=0;
struct nodo *lista=(struct nodo *)malloc(tam ); //Se reserva la cantidad de memoria a usar
lista=NULL;
printf("\nPrograma que lee los sexos alumnos e imprima el numero de mujeres");

for(i=0; i<T; i++) //Ciclo para ingresar los datos 
{
    struct nodo *p =(struct nodo *) malloc(tam); 
    printf("\nIngrese el dato %d: ",i+1);
    scanf(" %c", &(*p).sexo); 
    (*p).sig=lista;

}

for(i=0; i<T; i++)
{
    struct nodo *p =(struct nodo *) malloc(tam);
    p=lista;
    if((*p).sexo =='F')
    {
        totalf=totalf+1;
    }   
}
printf("El total de mujeres es: %i\n", totalf);
}
```

Comment: Please read: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I dont understand this program. On first glance, I see 2 major problems: 1) you allocate "lista" then make it NULL. That will crash your loop. And 2) the printf formatter for an integer is %d not %i.

Comment: Allocating memory with `struct nodo *lista=(struct nodo *)malloc(tam );` followed by `lista=NULL;` is *una carretera al infierno*.

Comment: You are not building the linked list correctly. Every allocated node is pointing to `lista` (which was set to `NULL` before the first loop). You then lose the value of `p` in each iteration of the first loop. You instead need to *append* nodes to the back of the linked list.

Comment: @Goodies [`%i`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx) is good for integer output.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of problems in your code like

1. `struct nodo *lista=(struct nodo *)malloc(tam ); 
    lista=NULL;` here first allocated memory and immediately you make it NULL, that serves no purpose, instead don't allocate any memory for `lista` and initialize to `NULL`, this will be your `headptr`
2. Secondly in the `for(i=0; i<T; i++){ /*.. */ }` there is no link established b/w nodes.Learn how to add or link nodes.

here is the Working one, I putted explanation in comments

```
struct nodo{
        /*Declaración de los campos*/
        char sexo;
        struct nodo *sig; //Uso de sig como apuntador dentro de la lista al siguiente nodo
};
int tam= sizeof(struct nodo); //Se calcula el tamaño de bytes 
int main(){

        int i, totalf=0;
        struct nodo *lista = NULL; /* this is your head pointer */

        printf("\nPrograma que lee los sexos alumnos e imprima el numero de mujeres");

        for(i=0; i<T; i++) {
                struct nodo *p =(struct nodo *) malloc(tam); /* new node everytime */
                printf("\nIngrese el dato %d: ",i+1);
                scanf(" %c", &(*p).sexo); /* put daata into memory */
                (*p).sig = lista; /* make new node next as head node */
                lista = p; /*update the head node */

        }
        struct nodo *temp = lista; /* temp points to head node */
        for(i=0; i<T; i++) {
                if((*temp).sexo =='F'){ /* check temp data matches or not */
                        totalf=totalf+1;
                }   
                temp = (*temp).sig; /* this you forget ? update temp */
        }
        printf("El total de mujeres es: %i\n", totalf);
        return 0;
}
```

Read any good C book to learn data structure.